# How discord.py knows which function to pass the event data?

Tags: python, events, python-decorators, discord.py

I am currently using [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) and I was curious about how the `Client.event` decorator works, but I can't find out for example, when it pass the data to the `on_message` function when there is a message event.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    pass

client.run('token')
```

When there is a message it takes the `on_message` function and pass the message to it, but I can't find when that happens in the code.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it happens in the [`dispatch` method](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py#L318) where it concatenates the prefix "on_" with the name of the event, finds the relevant method via `getattr`, then calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the problem but I suggest you use the [Discord API](https://discordapp.com/invite/discord-API) server to ask for anything API related, you will find proficient API users there for all programming languages on their respective channels and if you're lucky you can catch the developers too.